# Could jet engines have a grille to prevent bird or drone entry?

Tags: jet-engine, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

A bird, or indeed any object, entering a jet engine is a very undesirable situation and may cause engine failure. There are also fears we're not far away from seeing the first incident of a drone entering a jet engine.

Why do we not see grilles or cages on the front of the jet engines to prevent this happening?

Comment: Any grill that is closed enough to keep bird/drone parts from entering the engine is going to seriously impede the airflow into the engine itself.

Comment: While the other question's answers state that this is *not possible* due to aerodynamic losses, weight, ice collection, etc. yet nobody provides figures to sustain this statement. So the answers could be improved, or this question reformulated into asking for the **feasibility** (it seems possible) and consequences on the **cost** of such device.

Comment: A grille over the front of an engine will not stop a bird from entering the engine of a plane going at a few hundred knots. It will just stop a complete bird from entering, it will however now be in manageable chunks.
If the aircraft is going slow enough not to mince the bird you will now have a bird sized blockage in the airflow in addition to the surface area of the grille. At least if the bird enters the engine there is still a chance that the turbine can mash the bird into manageable mush.